# Does ST have a separate Cortex M4F series or are its M4 parts essentially M4Fs?

Tags: microcontroller, stm32, arm, cortex-m

ST's website does not use the term M4F. Also there is no filter for Hardware Floating Point Unit in parametric search so I guess ST includes floating point unit in all M4 parts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes all Cortex M4 from ST include a floating point unit and are thus essentially Cortex M4F.

Other manufacturers do this differently. Like pointed out in the comments there is Microchip with the [SAM4C](http://www.microchip.com/wwwproducts/en/ATSAM4C16) has a dual core implementation where one has a FPU and one has not.

So keep looking when you change to a different manufacturer.

Comment: They exist, SAM4C is dual core, one with, one without for example.

Comment: @SeanHoulihane yeah like I expected. One thing which I learned: if a specification allows something to be done - it is done, regardless of how strange it might seem from the own standpoint.